# Installing shell extension using Desktop Bridge

Tags: uwp, shell-extensions, desktop-bridge, appx, desktop-app-converter

My Win32 application needs to install a Windows Explorer Shell extension.

I've used Desktop App Converter to generate AppX for my application. But the converter ignored the shell extension installed by a legacy installer of the application.

While it captured the `Classes\Directory\shellex` key to `Registry.dat`, the key entries point to CLSID that was not captured. And even if it did capture the referenced CLSID, it points to a path, where legacy installer installs the application, not to a real location where AppX will be installed.

---

I was thinking about registering the extension by the application itself on the first run. But the installation location in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` has restricted permissions, so `regsvr32` fails.

> The module "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WinSCP_5.14.0.0_x86__2dz6xbp7ps3z2\DragExt64.dll" failed to load.
>
> Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
>
> Access is denied.

---

The permissions do allow the file to be copied elsewhere though. So I could copy the .dll to for example user profile (`C:\Users\...`) and register it from there. But that would leave the .dll behind, when the AppX is uninstalled.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: AFAIK Registring shell extensions requires modifying system registry which is not possible in a Desktop Bridge app, no matter which path you go through. Desktop Bridge apps are isolated when it comes to editing system registry.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz Yes, it's possible. But maybe there's an alternative way, like there's for registering file extensions.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes) you can find that when you write to registry, you write to a local .dat file not the actual system registry. Also, regsvr32  needs administrator permission while Desktop Bridge apps run on the user context not as administrator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The design principle for packaged Win32 apps on Windows 10 (Desktop Bridge apps) is that they integrate with the Shell in a declarative way via the appxmanifest (not via registry). To facilitate this we have added Shell extensions to the manifest scheme. The system will run those extensions out-of-proc with the Shell (unlike classic in-proc extensions), to allow seamless app updates and to prevent apps from the crashing the Windows Shell/Explorer.

See here for documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions

**EDIT**
Note that not all existing Shell extensions are supported today. To help us prioritize any that are still missing, please log them on UserVoice:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform

Comment: Thanks for your response. My shell extension implements `ICopyHook`. It does not look like that this is supported in Desktop Bridge extensions.

Comment: Yes, this one is still on the backlog for Desktop Bridge applications. I have updated my answer with info on how you can help us prioritize the Shell extensions that are not yet supported in Desktop Bridge apps.

Comment: To help with the tendency of the right click menu to become bloated, I would like to be able to toggle an extension.  (with a checkbox in the app's options menu)  Is there a way to do this that isn't restricted for converted apps?

Comment: The link to uservoice is broken. Are there any plans to add Shell Namespace Extension in Windows 11? Or are there any replacement for them on Windows 11?